# Paypal and reseller commission

Tags: paypal

I have a web site that is a customer to customer (C2C) service. Example, a user is looking for a hockey card of Gordie Howe and another customer wants to sell a Gordie Howe hockey card. If they sell the card 100$, I'd like to have 90$ that goes to the seller and 10$ that goes to me for providing the service (some kind of a reseller commission).

Is there a way of doing this with in a single payment with paypal?

Comment: Should be closed as not-programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the $100 go to you and you cut a check to the customer monthly for their proceeds.

Comment: Simple thinking. But is there any way to do it through coding to reduce much manual work?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for something like google checkout or another payment system tailored to merchants and not consumers.